# How to create a edgelist from a pandas datrafame?

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I have a pandas dataframe (df) with 1: connected vertices and 0: unconnected vertices

| X | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| G | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| H | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I need to convert this to a edgelist like:

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| F | B |
| F | C |
| G | D |
| H | C |

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using `stack()` and constructing a new df.

```
df2 = (pd.DataFrame(
    df.set_index('X').where(lambda x: x.ne(0)).stack().index.tolist(),
    columns = ['X','Target']))
```

or

```
df.set_index('X').mul(df.columns[1:]).where(lambda x: x.ne('')).stack().droplevel(1).reset_index().set_axis(['X','Target'],axis=1)
```

or

```
df.set_index('X').dot(df.columns[1:] + ',').str.strip(',').str.split(',').explode().reset_index().set_axis(['X','Target'],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   X Target
0  F      B
1  F      C
2  G      D
3  H      C
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `melt`, filter and cleanup:

```
out = (df
   .melt('X', var_name='Target')
   .loc[lambda d: d.pop('value').eq(1)]
   .rename(columns={'X': 'Source'})
 )
```

Output:

```
  Source Target
0      F      B
3      F      C
5      H      C
7      G      D
```

Alternative with `stack`:

```
out = (df
   .replace(0, pd.NA)
   .set_index('X')
   .stack()
   .rename_axis(['Source', 'Target'])
   .reset_index()
   .drop(columns=0)
 )
```

Output:

```
  Source Target
0      F      B
1      F      C
2      G      D
3      H      C
```